# Visual Studio 2017 Custom Checkin Policy Extension Registration

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, policy

Hi I upgrade my custom policy to vs2017 but I got policy assembly is not registered,there is nothing in ActivityLog and I cant understand root cause,also I try in exprimantel mode but nothing is attach,I only got error in tfs checkin page How can I understand root cause of this,Is there any track mechanism for that

> Internal error in xxx Check-In Policy. Error loading the xxx Check-In
>   Policy policy (The policy assembly 'xxx.Policies, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=54e79ebc0sacbf' is not registered.).
>   Installation instructions:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove all Microsoft.TeamFoundation.*** and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.*** dlls and I add new versions of visualstudio 2017(versions 15.0.0.0) versions of these dlls from 
...\Visual Studio 2017\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer